# Ansible - How to check postgresql table changes ?

Tags: database, postgresql, ansible

I want to run an ansible task if an entry updated/deleted/inserted to a postgresql table that I created.

I'm looking for a convenient way to achieve this. Is it possible to do that without developing my own module?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with Postgres (starting with 9.3) trigger of course. But I think **it would be a bad idea**. Anyway just to demonstrate the way you can run a shell command on data change:

```
t=# create user no_priv password 'p';
CREATE ROLE
t=# create table r (t text); --to copy from program to
CREATE TABLE
t=# create or replace function bad_idea() returns trigger as
$$
begin
execute format ($f$copy r from program 'echo %s'$f$,TG_OP);
return new;
end;
$$ language plpgsql security definer;
CREATE FUNCTION
t=# create table bi (i int);
CREATE TABLE
t=# create trigger t before insert ON bi execute procedure bad_idea();
CREATE TRIGGER
t=# insert into bi select 0;
INSERT 0 1
t=# insert into bi select 0;
INSERT 0 1
t=# select * from r;
   t
--------
 INSERT
 INSERT
(2 rows)
t=# grant all on bi, r to no_priv;
GRANT
```

now reasonable question what user no_priv and grants are for. You need a superuser to copy from program for obvious reason. In order to overcome it we use security definer on function creation and so to demonstrate that not superuser still can run a program:

```
MacBook-Air:~ vao$ psql -h 192.168.8.110 -d t -U no_priv
Password for user no_priv:
Timing is on.
psql (9.6.1, server 9.6.3)
SSL connection (protocol: TLSv1.2, cipher: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, bits: 256, compression: off)
Type "help" for help.

t=> insert into bi select 0;
INSERT 0 1
Time: 53.883 ms
t=> select * from r;
   t
--------
 INSERT
 INSERT
 INSERT
(3 rows)

Time: 72.457 ms
```